# Buscar apenas um valor via shell script

Tags: rest, shell-script

Galera,

Estou criando um script para buscar um valor, porem, dentro do BDD existem valores repetidos e eu gostaria de buscar apenas um de cada. Por exemplo, existe varias unidades para cada estado, mas eu quero buscar apenas a unidade principal. Sao 28 unidades principais e 720 unidades secundarias. As 720 unidades secundarias tem como "unidade Pai" uma das 28 unidades principais.

Por exemplo², o estado Sao Paulo tem 150 unidades, porem, apenas uma é a principal e consequentemente se torna "unidade pai" das outras 149 unidades.

Enfim, toda vez que realizo uma busca de unidade ela me retorna todas, porem, eu quero somente que me retorne as unidades principais. O id delas vai de 1 até 28.

A busca é realizada via rest, através do shell script.

Comment: Poderia colocar algum código para exemplificar melhor a sua pergunta.

Comment: Como é o formato da resposta do rest? Json bonitificado? XML em uma única linha? CSV? Texto puro? Como saber qual é o principal? Como identifico o id de cada objeto?

Comment: Normalmente o rest retorna uma espécie de dados profunda (ie, objetos dentro de objetos), não necessariamente rasa. Se você não tiver um objeto raso, você só pode interpretar de maneira correta usando um identificador para linguagens livre de contexto, que são mais poderosos do que expressões regulares. Para casos de objetos profundos, outra linguagem é mais adequada, como m4, Java, Python etc

Comment: Olá, eu acabei resolvendo isso buscando cada id das unidades pais, por exemplo:
rest/gestao/Unidade?id=1&id=2&id=3... etc.

Nao foi a melhor solução, mas resolveu meu problema.

Agradeço suas respostas!

Comment: Olá Letícia, que bom que resolveu sua questão. Você se importaria de postar a sua resposta para que seja útil para quem tenha a mesma dúvida?